# std::chrono::duration < rep, ratio> template parameter inquiry to establish own duration objects

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have `std::chrono::duration< Rep, Period >`, and I understand that Rep is pertaining to what format you want the duration count to be transcribed in and Period is an std::ratio< n, d> where the numerator is the amount of seconds and the denominator is the amount to get a single unit. But as I'm looking over the internet, I find `std::chrono::duration < int , std::ratio<60, 1>> minute ( 60 );` says

> Expected parameter declarator [ missing_param ]

when I look at reference std::chrono::milliseconds has two properties, rep and period.

the exact code is

```
#include <string>            
                           
#include <chrono>            
#include <ratio>

class object {
    private:
              
        std::string location ;          
              
        std::chrono::milliseconds creation(30) ;

    protected:           
    public:              
};
```

when I put this in, `std::chrono::milliseconds<int , std::ratio<1,1000>> creation;` and an error likes this shoots out

> Expected member name or ';'

now keeping in consideration that just making an instance of this with no params creates the error

> In template: no member named 'value' in 'std::chrono::__is_duration'

code looks something similar to `std::chrono::miliseconds creation;`

I'm using Ale for VIM to get the errors, i believe ALE returns it's own variations of GNU CPP Compiler. I could be mistaken. Ale is a linter.

Comment: What compiler and standard library are you using, which which build options? What exact code are you trying to compile for each error? "code looks something similar to" is not enough; show the _exact_ code.

Comment: yeah cpplearner, that answers my question perfectly.